# Play-Framework 2.2: How to access model private field in temlate

Tags: compiler-errors, java-8, playframework-2.2

I have a pojo user class, which have private fields and public getter/setter. When i trying to access private fields using template expression language, the play framework generate an compile time error. Follwoing is my code:

Model Class:

```
public class User extends AbstractEntity{
@Id
@Getter @Setter
private Long id;
@Required
@Getter @Setter
private String name;
@Getter @Setter
private String age;
@Getter @Setter
private List<Car> cars;

public User() {}
public User(Long id, String name, String age){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

In model class, i am using project `lombok` for generating `getter/setter`.

Template :

```
<h1>All Users</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for(user <- users){
        <tr>
            <td>@user.id</td>
            <td>@user.name</td>
            <td>@user.age</td>
        </tr>
    }   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When compile the code, play geneate following error:

```
[error] /home/james/eclipse_workspace/playcrud/play-crud/app/views/user/all_users.scala.html:16: 
variable id in class User cannot be accessed in com.harmeetsingh13.entities.User
[error]                                 <td>@user.id</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play 'template expression language' is simply Scala code. Since fields you want to access are private you ought to use your public getters.

```
@for(user <- users){
    <tr>
        <td>@user.getId</td>
        <td>@user.getName</td>
        <td>@user.getAge</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Hello @Daniel Olszewski this is not working, still get compilation error. `[error] /home/james/eclipse_workspace/playcrud/play-crud/app/views/user/all_users.scala.html:16: value getId is not a member of com.harmeetsingh13.entities.User
[error]                                 <td>@user.getId</td>
`

Comment: Could you try to generate getters with your IDE and remove @Getter @Setter annotations? This might be a problem with `lombok`.

Comment: Hey @Daniel Olszewski this is work now. But why this happen ?

Comment: I don't know how lombok works, but it seems that it doesn't play well with the Play's compilation life cycle.